# BizTalk AS/2 implementation certificates

Tags: certificate, biztalk

I cannot add any certificates on AS2 messages in BizTalk.
So here's what I have for the moment (I have installed 2 certificates on the BizTalk machine using the same account as the on under which the Host Instance is running.

The 2 certificates are the following and placed in the locations:

\Personal\Certificates - My own certificate 'pfx'.
\Other People\Certificates - Party certificate 'cer'.

So far the importing of the certificates.
Now, when in BizTalk Administration, I go to Parties and I go on the agreement between the parties. In that window I go down to 'Signature certificate' and I check "Override group signing certificate". Then when I click "browse" I see:

"No certificate available."
"No certificates meet the application criteria".

Any idea on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it. The certificates should be installed under the same instance that the BizTalk Administration Console is openend. Otherwise the certificates could not be found.